# Error Angular, no reconoce el tipo de datos en subscribe de Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Estoy intentando realizar un subcribe de un metodo llamado desde mi servicio pero al usar la respuesta del subscribe me da un error al parecer por el tipo devuelto aunque en mi servicio especifique el tipo.

Este es mi servicio

```
import { Injectable, Query } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RespuestaMDB } from '../interfaces/interfaces';
import { environment } from '../..//environments/environment';

const URL = environment.url;
const apiKey = environment.apiKey;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MoviesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private ejecutarQuery<T>( query: string ){

    query = URL + query;
    query += `&api_key=${ apiKey }&language=es&include_image_language=es`;

    return this.http.get( query );

  }


  getFeature() {

    return this.ejecutarQuery<RespuestaMDB>(`/discover/movie?primary_release_date.gte=2023-11-01&primary_release_date.lte=2023-11-30`);
  }

}
```

Y aqui estoy suscribiendo ese metodo getFeature()

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.moviesService.getFeature()
    .subscribe( resp => {
      console.log(resp.results); // Error: La propiedad 'results' no existe en el tipo 'Object'.
      this.peliculasRecientes = resp.results; // Error: La propiedad 'results' no existe en el tipo 'Object'.
      
    })
  }
```

Al intentar colocar (resp: RespuestaMDB) me dice:
La sobrecarga 1 de 2, "(observerOrNext?: Partial<Observer> | ((value: Object) => void) | undefined): Subscription", dio el error siguiente.
No se puede asignar un argumento de tipo "(resp: RespuestaMDB) => void" al parámetro de tipo "Partial<Observer> | ((value: Object) => void) | undefined".

Alguien me ayuda por favor?

Comment: Tipa los métodos de tu servicio. Has creado un método con tipo T pero luego no lo usas en el método, para qué le has puesto esa T entonces? `return this.http.get<T>(...)`. Además podrías anotar también el método en si: `private ejecutarQuery<T>( query: string ): T {...}`. Si es que ese `T` es el tipo que pretendes obtener, es difícil de saber exactamente dado que no tiene uso :) Si no tipas los métodos que usas y haces llamadas genéricas (el http.get) typescript acaba perdiendo la información del tipado.

Comment: Gracias, fue de mucha ayuda, me puedes explicar un poco el sentido de tipar el get y xq esto resuelve?

Comment: El sentido de tipar el get?? Pues es obvio, lo acabas de ver. SI no tipas el get, devuelve por defecto `Object`, y luego cuando quieras usar lo que has obtenido tienes problemas porque es tipo `Object` y no lo que tú esperas. De esta manera le estás indicando que tiene que devolver ese tipo, y así typescript es capaz de saber qué objeto tienes ahí para trabajar. TypeScript no hace magia, no puede saber de manera innata qué va a devolver un método genérico porque... bueno, es genérico! Puede devolver cualquier cosa, es tu trabajo decirle qué devuelve en cada caso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta tipar la llama a get:

```js
 private ejecutarQuery<T>( query: string ){

    query = URL + query;
    query += `&api_key=${ apiKey }&language=es&include_image_language=es`;
    //Esta es la razón de que falle. 
    return this.http.get<T>( query );

  }
```

Comment: Excelente, con esto se resolvió, gracias. Pero de ser posible me puedes explicar el xq de esto? Xq daba el error en el page y colocando eso se resuelve?

Comment: Typescript trata de inferir el tipo automático siempre y cuando este no sea algún tipo `any` ó `unknow`. El método `get` por defecto es `object`, pero si defines su tipado "diamante" (No recuerdo si así se llama) sobre escribes el tipo que retorna y hace un "casting" forzado. Esto sería similar a hacer `const respuestaCasteada = resp as RespuestaMDB`. Probablemente te de otro error si lo haces así, y te pide que lo mandes a `unknow` primero, pero la idea es esa.